# How to use HoloEverywhere theme in Eclipse?

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock, android-theme, android-holo-everywhere

I face problems with holo everywhere theme and ABS:

1) I have downloaded HoloEverywhere-master project from [HoloEveryWhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere)

2) I go to File - Import - Projects from Git - URI Into Location - URI: github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere.git and Marked only master branch and downloaded items. 4 project imported to my workplace. Now there is a red ! sign on all of them.

3) I have download sherlockActionBar from [github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock](http://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock)

4) I add HoloEverywhere Library to my project from project properties->android -> add library and now android doesn't recognize R file says "R cannot be resolved to a variable".

now I dont know what to do? I searched everywhere in the net but there where no proper answer. I'm new with android and I should use it, I'll be thankful if there is a simple step by step way to use ABS and HoloEverywhereTheme.

Comment: Why do you use ABS? HoloEverywhere 2.* works with ABC. If you *really* want to use ABS use HoloEverywhere v1.6.8. But this version has known errors and it's not mantained any more.

Comment: My main problem is how to use HoloEverywhere theme I searched and I saw that they use ABS sometimes with HoloEverywhere and I think it is necessary for HoloEverywhere and I download it. I dont know how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Your Activity must extend `org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity`

Please read for further details here: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/wiki/Basic-migration-on-HoloEverywhere

Comment: you mean change "public class Main extends Activity {" to "public class Main extends org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity" in my Main activity?

Comment: ok, then i think you have an error in one of your xml files. R compiles automatically. see you any error in your project?

Comment: My main.xml file contains just an empty Relative Layout. The project has a red "!" on it in workspace. Any idea?

Comment: ah ok, then i think you don't have add the a lib/lib-project not correct to your project. Before of all, if you use eclipse go to "Window" -> "Show View" -> "Problems" then you have an overview of all your errors and warning, there you can see your Problems in your project. Back2Topic, Right click on your project and go to properties, then please check your build path options, there you must add the HoloEverywhere Project-Lib

Comment: This is what I see there: http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-01/79019167845350100164.jpg

Comment: I have added HoloEverywhere Library project to it

Comment: ok and where is the jar? Please check the folder C:/Users/Mohammad/git/HoloEvrywhere/library/bin for the missing jar. simple put the missing jar into this folder and finish. Another solutuion, copy the missing jar into your project (create a folder libraries and paste it into this folder) then you can refer directly to this.

Comment: Where can I find HoloEverywhere library.jar file? I cant find a file with this name. I only have a 2k size file named "HoloEverywhere.java"

Comment: ok i have downloaded the Project and you right, the jar is missing, you can try to change the path to C:\Users\Mohammad\Downloads\git\HoloEverywhere\library\libs I'm not sure if this right but another jar is not presented